# Software that support around 100000 mails in an hour

Tags: open-source, email, newsletter

I am for looking for good mailing software for sending promotional mails.

It should support around 100000 mails in an hour. Does anyone know about  software, either paid or free, for business promotion mails?

It's for my business promotion, mails to increase the conversion. Around 300000 customers registered on website and weekly I want to send a mail. Mails would be personalize with name. Yes I want Database or admin panel where I can see how many opened & unsubscribe.

mails includes images, brand logo, unsubscribe link, android & apple app link & content.

Comment: Generally, you should not handle mailing yourself, you can end up on spam lists. Better let a reputable company do the actual mailing; they know how to handle bounces, spam complaints, unsubscribe requests. Two names that come to mind are MailChimp and AWeber.

Comment: Maybe try [convertkit](http://mbsy.co/gfhHg).  They do limit your email quantity a bit, and it might seem a bit expensive at first, but the segmentation, sequencing, and automation features are extremely powerful for your business.  Also consider [Sendy](http://sendy.co), which costs a ton less, but might not be quite as advanced.  Definitely supports your email count requirement though.  It's self hosted and runs through Amazon SES.